# Streaming generated word file with python-docx

Tags: python, django, file, streaming, python-docx

I have to generate very large word document using [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/) library, so is it possible to stream this file while generating it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it won't come easy. I've heard of it but never heard of or seen it actually being done.

If you look at page 86 of this Office Open XML Packaging Conventions document: https://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%202%20-%20Open%20Packaging%20Conventions.pdf you'll see talk of "Streaming Creation", just after "Streaming Consumption". So it is something that was considered in the Open Packaging Convention (OPC) design.

As far as I know there is no library support for this, so you would probably be on your own for quite a bit. `python-docx` is not stream oriented, it generates parts in-memory (as an `lxml` graph) and then only serializes those on saving.

So the question of *why* you want to stream them will become important, like if some part is IO bound or you just want to get a head start on downloading while you're generating. Aside from IO (like perhaps database access or something), generating a file should be *much*, *much* faster than feeding it into the wire.

You'll also need some support on the client side to reassemble the package. In `python-pptx` you'll see support for loading a document (package) from a directory-tree of part files (like a pre-expanded Zip archive; a .docx file is a Zip archive). So that would be one approach, like downloading is populating a directory of files that can then either be zipped up into a .docx file or opened from directly.